# HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes - Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache-flink

When I try to submit a job to Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT, it throws the exception
`org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes.` I can see rhis exception in logs. I tried to the increase value of `akka.framesize` and set it 104857600b , but it still throws the error.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT is *not* a released version of Flink and changes with every commit on the development branch. Since the behavior of a SNAPSHOT version is not fixed, it doesn't make much sense to ask questions about them on Stack Overflow. Please reach out with questions to the community via [user or dev mailing lists](http://flink.apache.org/community.html#mailing-lists) or report a bugs in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK).

Answer (score 0):

looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7521 may be the right issue to follow